# The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I'm developing purchase module with ASP.NET MVC 5. In Create view purchase, I'm using PartialView to load the detail purchase.

The Detail Purchase contains:

- A textbox with browse button to input item
- A textbox to input quantity
- A button to add the item to the list (purchase detail)

When I clicked browse button the modal will show up with list of paged items (using PagedList). The modal form contains:

- In modal header there are a textbox and a button for searching item name
- In modal body to display list of items (load partially)

The error occurs if I searched item name

> "The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function
>   object"

The jQuery script is already added by default at ~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml, and in the create view, I have added `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Code: **View Create Purchase (Create.cshtml)**

```
@model SalesSupportSystem.ViewModels.PurchaseOrderViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PurchaseOrder</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderDate)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceNo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PurchaseOrderDetail/_AddEdit.cshtml", Model.PurchaseOrderAddEditDetails); }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".date").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                clearBtn: true,
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                todayBtn: "linked",
                todayHighlight: true
            });

            $("#btnLookupItem").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/INVENTSUM1/Lookup")",
                    cache: false
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $("#itemContainer").html(data);
                    $("#itemModal").modal("show");
                });
            });

            $("#btnSubmitINVENTSUM1").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/INVENTSUM1/Lookup")",
                    data: { filterValue: $("#FilterValue").val() },
                    cache: false
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $("#itemContainer").html(data);
                });
            });
        });

        function setINVENTSUM1(ITEMID, ITEMNAME) {
            document.getElementById("ItemID").value = ITEMID;
            document.getElementById("ItemName").value = ITEMNAME;
            $("#itemModal").modal("hide");
        }
    </script>
}
```

**PartialView (_AddEdit.cshtml)**

```
@model SalesSupportSystem.ViewModels.PurchaseOrderDetailAddEditViewModel

<!-- Item Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="itemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" id="btnCancelCUSTTABLE" title="Clear the selected input on form" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select Item</h4>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Lookup", "INVENTSUM1"))
                {
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        Find by name: <input type="text" id="FilterValue" name="FilterValue" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter keyword" value="" />
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmitCUSTTABLE" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="itemContainer">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEdit", "PurchaseOrderDetail", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    <h4>Detail</h4>
    <hr />
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ItemID)
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemName)
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnLookupItem">...</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantityOrder)
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddItem">Add</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller (INVENTSUM1Controller.cs)**

```
public ActionResult Lookup(int? page)
{
    var pagedItem =  db.INVENTSUM1
                       .OrderBy(i => i.ITEMNAME)
                       .ToPagedList(page, 10);

    return PartialView("_Lookup", pagedItem);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Lookup(string filterValue)
{
    var pagedItem =  db.INVENTSUM1
                       .Where(i => i.ITEMNAME.Contains(filterValue))
                       .OrderBy(i => i.ITEMNAME)
                       .ToPagedList(1, 10);

    return PartialView("_Lookup", pagedItem);
}
```

**PartialView (_Lookup.cshtml)**

```
@model IEnumerable<SalesSupportSystem.Models.INVENTSUM1>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{
    var pagedList = (PagedList.IPagedList)Model;
}

<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEMID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEMNAME)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:setINVENTSUM1('@item.ITEMID', '@item.ITEMNAME')" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></a></td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEMID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEMNAME)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>

Page @(pagedList.PageCount < pagedList.PageNumber ? 0 : pagedList.PageNumber) of @pagedList.PageCount
<div id="pager">
    @Html.PagedListPager(pagedList, page => Url.Action("Lookup", new { page }))
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pager").on("click", "a", function () {
            if (this.href == "") {
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: this.href,
                cache: false
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#itemContainer").html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another question: as you can see in the lookup.cshtml code, I placed script at there. I've read from SO articles, it should not be placed in partialview, but I have no choice, if I placed in Create.cshtml, the paging will not work. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: in your layout.cshtml, does your jquery script come before scripts section?

Comment: You are attempting to use the jQuery `$` variable before it has been assigned. As failedprogramming suggests, this is most likely because your script references are not in the correct order, although you haven't actually shown us the part of your code we need to see to confirm that.

Comment: @failedprogramming in layout.cshtml, I call the script in following order:

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")`
`@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

Comment: set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations in BundleConfig to false. Then check your Html to make sure all scripts are there and in correct order. Also are you including regular or minified versions of scripts in your bundles?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm using default Internet template, and if I need another script I will add in `@section Scripts`. Could you explain what's kind of correct order should I follow? What's part of code I haven't shown up? I only remove the css bootstrap for brevity

Comment: i can't tell which part of your code is causing the errors. It could be that your _AddEdit view has a script that uses jQuery. This could be true especially if your jquery script reference comes after your @RenderBody in your _layout view. Make sure any scripts in _AddEdit are reference in a Scripts section. One thing you could try is to move your jquery script reference to the <head> of your layout view and see if that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined in IE 10 The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734247/script5009-json-is-undefined-in-ie-10-the-value-of-the-property-is-null-o)