# SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, undefined

I am new to JSP with jQuery coding. I have written code by using jQuery to validate the form with username and password.

problem is while page loading getting the below exception:

> SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Code snippet is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/libs/jquery.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $ (document.documentElement ).ready ( function() {
        $('#login').click(function() {
            var username = $('#user').val();
            var password = $('#pass').val();
            if (username == "") {
                $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span>Please provide Username</span>");
                return false;
            }
            if (password == "") {
                $('#dis').slideDown().html('<span id="error">Please provide Password</span>');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

when I am providing url its executing..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"/></script>
```

and in dispatch servlet.xml I do have mapping like..

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/js/libs/**" location="classpath:resources/js/libs/jquery.min.js" />
```

and in web.xml file I have added..

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but still getting the above error at line where $ is started with ready function.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It should be `$(document).ready` not `$ (document.documentElement ).ready`

Comment: Thanks andy,even i have used like that as well , but it doesn't work.

Comment: does your jquery library exist at "/resources/js/libs/jquery.min.js" are you 100% sure?

Comment: Yes it's there in context path. i.e under projectname/src/main/webapps/resources/js/libs/jquery.min.js. how ever the issue resolved now, thanks for your time.. how means.. i have created project name Invoice_Archive_Gui. here '_'  undersquare is the problem.. so modifed project by removing '_' undersquare, then jquery doesn't have any problem to exute in jsp while loading.

Comment: solution already defined in the below link..                                                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785705/0x800a138f-javascript-runtime-error-the-value-of-the-property-is-null-or?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined in IE 10 The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734247/script5009-json-is-undefined-in-ie-10-the-value-of-the-property-is-null-o)